# Variable null problem while trying to pass it to a function Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I'm trying to pass a variable "latLngList" that must be used to check if the user is near an area with too much noise (by consulting a database). Still, the main issue is that I'm having some trouble with it because the "latLngList" is null when I try to execute the "verificarNivelRuidoEPosicao()" function. I have already tried to call the "consulta()" function before the "getcurrentLocation()", but it doesn't seems to work. It looks like the "verificarNivelRuidoEPosicao()" function references the latLngList without being populated first (and therefore, the variable is a null list).
I really don't know anymore where to run.
My Main class beginning and its onCreate:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

companion object {
    private const val REQUEST_CODE = 123 // Valor
}

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap

val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
var nivelRuido: Float = 0.0f
val NIVEL_RUIDO_ALERTA: Float = 65.00f
var userLocation: Location? = null
private val margemErro = 50
val dadosList = mutableListOf<IntegrasData>()
val latLngList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
var latitudeUser: Double? = null
var longitudeUser: Double? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        consulta()
        //limpar cache
        CacheUtils.clear(applicationContext)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        LocationPermissionHelper.checkLocationPermission(this) {
            // Verificar se a permissão ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION foi concedida
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

            } else {
                // A permissão não foi concedida, você pode solicitar a permissão ao usuário
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }
        }

        val mapFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapViewContainer) as? SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            val newMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mapViewContainer, newMapFragment)
                .commit()
            newMapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        } else {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        }
        val runnable = Runnable {
            // Código a ser executado na thread principal
            getCurrentLocation()
            consulta()
        }
        // Executa o código na thread principal após um atraso de 10 segundos para nao lotar o firebase de requisições e estourar o limite
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000)
}
```

The function that pulls data from the database:

```
 fun consulta() {
    val collectionRef = db.collection("IntegrasData")
    val dadosList = mutableListOf<IntegrasData>()
    val latLngList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()

    collectionRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
            for (documentSnapshot in querySnapshot) {

                val nivelRuido = documentSnapshot.getDouble("SPL")?.toFloat()
                val latitude = documentSnapshot.getDouble("Latitude")
                val longitude = documentSnapshot.getDouble("Longitude")

                // Lógica para manipular os dados
                if (nivelRuido != null && latitude != null && longitude != null) {

                    val dados = IntegrasData(nivelRuido, latitude, longitude)
                    val latLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)

                    latLngList.add(latLng)
                    dadosList.add(dados)
                    //verificarNivelRuidoEPosicao(latitude, longitude)

                }

            }
            for (dados in dadosList){
                verificarNivelRuidoEPosicao(dados.latitude, dados.longitude)
            }

            for (dados in dadosList) {
                Log.d(
                    TAG, "Nivel de ruido: ${dados.nivelRuido}\n" +
                            "Latitude: ${dados.latitude}\n" +
                            "Longitude: ${dados.longitude}\n" +
                            "dadosList: ${dadosList}\n" +
                            "latLngList: ${latLngList}"

                )
            }

            val heatMap = HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                .data(latLngList)
                .build()

            googleMap.addTileOverlay(TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(heatMap))

        }

        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            "Erro ao tentar consultar o banco de dados na coleção ${collectionRef}: ${exception}"
            // Lógica para lidar com erros
        }


}
```

The function that get my current location:

```
 private fun getCurrentLocation(): Location? {
    val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permissão de localização concedida

        // Obter a localização atual
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            0,
            0f,
            object : LocationListener {
                override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                    // Aqui está a posição atual do usuário
                    userLocation = location
                    latitudeUser = location.latitude
                    longitudeUser = location.longitude
                    Log.d(TAG, "\n*****userLocation: ${location} ******\n" +
                            "agora, se for assim: \n" +
                            "Latitude = ${latitudeUser}\n" +
                            "Longitude = ${longitudeUser}")
                    //Usar location.latitude e location.longitude!
                    // Faça o que for necessário com a posição atual
                    // ...


                    // Lembre-se de parar as atualizações de localização quando não precisar mais delas
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(this)
                }

                override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {}
            }
        )
    } else {
        // Permissão de localização não concedida, solicite ao usuário
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }
    return userLocation
}
```

A function that calculates the distance between two pairs of coordinates:

```
  private fun calcularDistancia(lat1: Double, lon1: Double, lat2: Double, lon2: Double): Float {
    val results = FloatArray(1)
    Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results)
    return results[0]
}
```

And finally the function that suppose to check if the user is near that area with high intensity sounds:

```
   private fun verificarNivelRuidoEPosicao(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    // Verifique os níveis de ruído e posição do usuário e emita alertas conforme necessário
    try{
        for (value in latLngList) {
            /*TODO fazer a iteração da lista do dadosList*/
            //if (value.latitude == userLocation!!.latitude && value.longitude == userLocation!!.longitude)

            val distancia = calcularDistancia(
                userLocation!!.latitude,
                userLocation!!.longitude,
                latitude,
                longitude
            )
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "Distancia: ${distancia}*\n"
            )
            if (distancia <= margemErro && nivelRuido >= NIVEL_RUIDO_ALERTA) {
                emitirAlertaRuido()
                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "Distancia: ${distancia}\n"
                )
            }

        }
    }
    catch (e: NullPointerException){
        Log.e(
            TAG, "Erro: latitudeUser e/ou longitudeUser está sendo passada como nulo!!" +
                    "\nlatitudeUser: ${latitudeUser}" +
                    "\nlongitudeUser: ${longitudeUser}\n" +
                    "Scheisse!"
        )
    }
}
```

A function that supposes to show notifications for the user if he's near that noisy area:

```
 fun emitirAlertaRuido(){
    val notificationId = 1

    // Crie um objeto NotificationCompat.Builder para construir a notificação
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sound)
        .setContentTitle("Alerta de ruído")
        .setContentText("Nível de ruído ultrapassado!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

    // Crie um objeto PendingIntent para abrir a atividade desejada ao clicar na notificação
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    // Obtenha uma referência ao NotificationManager
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Verifique se o dispositivo está executando o Android 8.0 (Oreo) ou posterior
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Crie um canal de notificação para dispositivos Android 8.0 e posterior
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "channel_id",
            "channel_id",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    // Construa e exiba a notificação usando o NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())

}
```